# Filling in a web form with splinter

Tags: python, splinter

I'm trying to write a script to fill in this web form. I am new to using the splinter library but after researching this is where I got:

```
from splinter import Browser

#data i would put in form
firstname = 'my_first_name_here'
lastname = 'my_last_name_here'
email_address = 'my_email_here'

browser = Browser('firefox')

#page to fill
browser.visit('https://www.nba.com/playoffdrive/')

browser.find_by_id('First Name').first.find_by_tag('input').fill(firstname)
browser.find_by_id('Last Name').first.find_by_tag('input').fill(lastname)
browser.find_by_id('Email Address').first.find_by_tag('input').fill(email_address)

browser.find_by_js('submit').first.click()

print browser.url

print browser.title

print browser.html
```

This is one of the errors i get:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What isn't working? :)

Comment: Yeah this is one of the errors i get:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: i'm not sure why i would need selenium when i'm using splinter